# react native yarn start using expo is not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to run the expo but nothing happens.

My try:

```
➜  expoTest git:(master) ✗ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ expo start
Starting project at /Users/seungjune/project/tutorial/expoTest
```

When I tried `npm start` or `yarn start` or `expo-cli start`, it still not working after the message as follows

`Starting project at  /Users/seungjune/project/tutorial/expoTest`

---

I found error after starting meesage as follows

```
(node:3581) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT] [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 65536.
    at validatePort (internal/validators.js:193:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1440:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:8:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at testPortAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:6:10)
    at availableAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:24:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:37:23
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at freePortRangeAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:33:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/freeport-async/index.js:43:18
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3581) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3581) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: share error code

Comment: Please, share more information. If you have more output, please, put on your question. This will help you to receive a faster and more right answer to your problem. Also, see about stackoverflow Code of Conduct in how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: There is no error code. I made new expo project by 'expo init expoTest' and typed yarn start. but nothing happened. sorry for my english skills. I will follow stackoverflow code of conduct. thank you.

Comment: I found error after starting meesage